# How to pull X amounts of previous data into row in CSV

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-2.7, csv

I have a very large CSV of data, and I need to append previous data to each row for each name in the column 2 for dates previous to the current one stipultated in column2. I think the easiest way to represent this problem is to provide a detailed example similar to my real data, but scaled down significantly:

```
Datatitle,Date,Name,Score,Parameter
data,01/09/13,george,219,dataa,text
data,01/09/13,fred,219,datab,text
data,01/09/13,tom,219,datac,text
data,02/09/13,george,229,datad,text
data,02/09/13,fred,239,datae,text
data,02/09/13,tom,219,dataf,text
data,03/09/13,george,209,datag,text
data,03/09/13,fred,217,datah,text
data,03/09/13,tom,213,datai,text
data,04/09/13,george,219,dataj,text
data,04/09/13,fred,212,datak,text
data,04/09/13,tom,222,datal,text
data,05/09/13,george,319,datam,text
data,05/09/13,fred,225,datan,text
data,05/09/13,tom,220,datao,text
data,06/09/13,george,202,datap,text
data,06/09/13,fred,226,dataq,text
data,06/09/13,tom,223,datar,text
data,06/09/13,george,219,dataae,text
```

So for threee first rows of this csv there is no previous data. So if we said we wanted to pull column 3 & 4 for the last 3 occurances of george (row1) on a date previous to the current one it would yeild:

```
data,01/09/13,george,219,dataa,text,x,y,x,y,x,y
```

However when previous data starts to become avaialble we would hope to produce a csv such as this:

```
Datatitle,Date,Name,Score,Parameter,LTscore,LTParameter,LTscore+1,LTParameter+1,LTscore+2,LTParameter+3,
data,01/09/13,george,219,dataa,text,x,y,x,y,x,y
data,01/09/13,fred,219,datab,text,x,y,x,y,x,y
data,01/09/13,tom,219,datac,text,x,y,x,y,x,y
data,02/09/13,george,229,datad,text,219,dataa,x,y,x,y
data,02/09/13,fred,239,datae,text,219,datab,x,y,x,y
data,02/09/13,tom,219,dataf,text,219,datac,x,y,x,y
data,03/09/13,george,209,datag,text,229,datad,219,dataa,x,y
data,03/09/13,fred,217,datah,text,239,datae,219,datab,x,y
data,03/09/13,tom,213,datai,text,219,dataf,219,datac,x,y
data,04/09/13,george,219,dataj,text,209,datag,229,datad,219,dataa
data,04/09/13,fred,212,datak,text,217,datah,239,datae,219,datab
data,04/09/13,tom,222,datal,text,213,datai,219,dataf,219,datac
data,05/09/13,george,319,datam,text,219,dataj,209,datag,229,datad
data,05/09/13,fred,225,datan,text,212,datak,217,datah,239,datae
data,05/09/13,tom,220,datao,text,222,datal,213,datai,219,dataf
data,06/09/13,george,202,datap,text,319,datam,219,dataj,209,datag
data,06/09/13,fred,226,dataq,text,225,datan,212,datak,217,datah
data,06/09/13,tom,223,datar,text,220,datao,222,datal,213,datai
data,06/09/13,george,219,datas,text,319,datam,219,dataj,209,datag
```

You will notice for the 06/09/13 george occurs twice and both times he has the same string `319,datam,219,dataj,209,datag` appended to his row. For the second time george appears he gets this same string appended because the george 3 rows above is on the same date. (This is just emphasising the "on a date previous to the current one."

As you can see from the column titles we are collecting the last 3 scores and the associated 3 parameters and appending them to each row. Please note, this is a very simplified example. In reality each date will contain a couple of thousand rows, in the real data there is also no pattern to the names, so we wouldnt expect to see fred,tom,george next to each other on a repeating pattern. If anyone can help me work out how best to achieve this (most efficient) I would be very greatful. If anything is unclear please let me know, I will add more detail. Any constructive comments appreciated. Thanks SMNALLY

Comment: is loading the data to a database an option for you?

Comment: Should the last line of the example data be ```data,06/09/13,george,219,datas,text```?  For two rows with the same Name and Date, the *most recent* row takes precedence and the older row is discarded - not used for any futher processing?

Comment: How large is the dataset?

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the questions, nope the last line  in the example is correct i need them both populated. The dataset is very large, so large I might have to break it up for detailed analysis.

Comment: Column four of the last row of the expected output is ```datas```.  None of the rows in the sample data contain ```datas```.

Comment: You are asking for efficient solutions.  The process is going to be  i/o bound.  Can you estimate magnitude of the data?  10M lines, 1G lines?  100 names, 10K names?

Comment: I have about 1M lines, and roughly 25k names (currently)

Comment: File size?  Are these line lengths representative?  What memory constraints are there?  What do you mean by efficient? how fast does it need to be?

Comment: The data file could easily be as much as 2gb in size. No the line lengths are not represenetative. At the moment 8gig DDR3. As efficient as possible. There is a strong chance this code will be used in day to day processes.

Comment: The header line in both the example input and output are missing the *text* field.

Comment: Are the rows equal length?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears your file is in date order. If we take the last entry per name per date, and add that to a sized deque for each name while writing out each row, that should do the trick:

```
import csv
from collections import deque, defaultdict
from itertools import chain, islice, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

# defaultdict whose first access of a key will create a deque of size 3
# defaulting to [['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x' ,'y']]
# Since deques are efficient at head/tail manipulation, then an insert to
# the start is efficient, and when the size is fixed it will cause extra
# elements to "fall off" the end... 
names_previous = defaultdict(lambda: deque([['x', 'y']] * 3, 3))
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as fin, open('sample_new.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    # Use groupby to detect changes in the date column. Since the data is always
    # asending, the items within the same data are contigious in the data. We use
    # this to identify the rows within the *same* date.
    # date=date we're looking at, rows=an iterable of rows that are in that date...
    for date, rows in groupby(islice(csvin, 1, None), itemgetter(1)):
        # After we've processed entries in this date, we need to know what items of data should
        # be considered for the names we've seen inside this date. Currently the data
        # is taken from the last occurring row for the name.
        to_add = {}
        for row in rows:
            # Output the row present in the file with a *flattened* version of the extra data
            # (previous items) that we wish to apply. eg:
            # [['x, 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y']] becomes ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', y'] 
            # So we're easily able to store 3 pairs of data, but flatten it into one long
            # list of 6 items...
            # If the name (row[2]) doesn't exist yet, then by trying to do this, defaultdict
            # will automatically create the default key as above.
            csvout.writerow(row + list(chain.from_iterable(names_previous[row[2]])))
            # Here, we store for the name any additional data that should be included for the name
            # on the next date group. In this instance we store the information seen for the last
            # occurrence of that name in this date. eg: If we've seen it more than once, then
            # we only include data from the last occurrence. 
            # NB: If you wanted to include more than one item of data for the name, then you could
            # utilise a deque again by building it within this date group
            to_add[row[2]] = row[3:5]            
        for key, val in to_add.iteritems():
            # We've finished the date, so before processing the next one, update the previous data
            # for the names. In this case, we push a single item of data to the front of the deck.
            # If, we were storing multiple items in the data loop, then we could .extendleft() instead
            # to insert > 1 set of data from above.
            names_previous[key].appendleft(val)
```

This keeps only the names and the last 3 values in memory during the run.

May wish to adjust to include correct/write new headers instead of just skipping those on input.

Comment: This code is genius, I was wondering if you might be able to comment it a little. In my example I have asked to pull in two paramaters each time. But in reality I need to pull in 5 or 6 parameters each time(from each row), and from my tinkering I cannot work out how this is achieved. Also I would love to be able to take some of the techniques used here and apply them to my own code!

Comment: Does this solution meet the requirement of avoiding appending scores from the same date? I'm not seeing a comparison for that anywhere, maybe the groupby or something?

Comment: Ok yeah looks like the groupby accumulates current date records into to_add list that won't be used until next time. Seems that it will not record multiple records for same name for same date though. That case was also not demonstrated with the sample data - adding a new date at bottom with george like '07/01/13' would show that two previous records for single date '06/09/13' should now appear in output, not just one.

Comment: @Mister_Tom I dont follow your comment?

Comment: @JonClements I am away tomorrow so cannot award the bounty. So I have awarded the bounty now in good faith that you may be able to provide the extra detail. All the best SMNALLY :)

Comment: When run against the example data, the output for the second and third name occurrence doesn't match the expected output. 2nd george: ```data,02/09/13,george,229,datad,text,219,dataa,x,y,x,y,x,y```. 3rd george: ```data,03/09/13,george,209,datag,text,229,datad,219,dataa,x,y,x,y,x,y```. Same for the other two names.  All other occurrences are ok.

Comment: Jon this isnt the first time I have used snippets of your code! Amazing stuff, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code sample that should demonstrate what you're looking for on the sample data provided with your question. I named my input file "input.csv" and read/write from the working directory, "output.csv" goes to the same folder. I used comments in the code to try to explain, storing previous records in a dictionary with lookup by name and storing a list of scores for each - storing current date records in a new buffer dictionary and adding that to the main dictionary each time the date changes in the input. Let me know if you have any questions, the code is a little rough - just a quick example. The [:6] slice gives the most recent 6 list items (three previous score/parameter pairs) for the current name.

```
import csv

myInput = open('input.csv','rb')
myOutput = open('output.csv','wb')
myFields = ['Datatitle','Date','Name','Score','Parameter','Text',
            'LTscore','LTParameter','LTscore+1','LTParameter+1',
            'LTscore+2','LTParameter+2']
inCsv = csv.DictReader(myInput,myFields)
outCsv = csv.writer(myOutput)
outCsv.writerow(myFields) # Write header row

previous_dict = dict() # store scores from previous dates
new_dict = dict() # buffer for records on current-date only

def add_new():
    # merge new_dict into previous_dict
    global new_dict, previous_dict
    for k in new_dict:
        if not previous_dict.has_key(k):
            previous_dict[k] = list()
        # put new items first
        previous_dict[k] = new_dict[k] + previous_dict[k]
    new_dict = dict() # reset buffer

old_date = '00/00/00' # start with bogus *oldest* date string
inCsv.next() # skip header row
for row in inCsv:
    myTitle = row['Datatitle']
    myDate = row['Date']
    myName = row['Name']
    myScore = row['Score']
    myParameter = row['Parameter']
    myText = row['Text']
    if old_date != myDate:
        add_new() # store new_dict buffer with previous data
        old_date = myDate
    if not new_dict.has_key(myName):
        new_dict[myName] = []
    # put new scores first
    new_dict[myName] = [myScore,myParameter] + new_dict[myName]
    if not previous_dict.has_key(myName):
        previous_dict[myName] = []
    outCsv.writerow([myTitle,myDate,myName,myScore,myParameter,myText] \
                     + previous_dict[myName][:6])
# end loop for each row

myInput.close()
myOutput.close()
```

My solution should do well for large data sets. If memory consumption is a concern, the length of the per-name lists can be limited to 3 scores - currently I'm keeping all previous scores and just displaying three in case you needed more in the future. If the size of data is unwieldy, you could always use a sqlite file database instead of a dict for temporary lookup data on disk rather than all in memory. With 8G of RAM and 2G of data, you should be fine with in-memory python dictionary as used here. Make sure you're using the 64-bit release of Python on a 64-bit OS. My example doesn't output anything to screen, but for a large file you may want to put a print statement that shows progress every N rows (like every 100, 1000, choose based on your system speed). Note that screen output slows down the speed of processing file data.

Comment: Great, I look forward to hearing whether this technique works for your problem.

Comment: I added some notes about efficiency and large data sets to my answer below the code example. Please try out the code and let me know how it goes. I'm hoping for a chance at that 100 bounty. Let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: @MisterTom Thanks for the notes, since this is the first model I am making in python (moving from vba) I am unsure what limitations I will hit along the way, so asking for any edits to be eddicient as a precausion.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents:
- Python 2.7.5
- I used a defaultdict to hold the previous rows for each *Name*.
- I used bounded length deques to hold previous rows because I liked the fifo behavior of a full deque.  It made it easy for me to think about it - just keep shoving stuff into it.
- I used operator.itemgetter() for indexing and slicing because it just reads better.

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
import csv
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter

# use a 3 item deque to hold the 
# previous three rows for each name
deck3 = partial(deque, maxlen = 3)
data = defaultdict(deck3)


name = itemgetter(2)
date = itemgetter(1)
sixplus = itemgetter(slice(6,None))

fields = ['Datatitle', 'Date', 'Name', 'Score', 'Parameter',
          'LTscore', 'LTParameter', 'LTscore+1', 'LTParameter+1',
          'LTscore+2', 'LTParameter+3']
with open('data.txt') as infile, open('processed.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    # comment out the next line if the data file does not have a header row
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        default = deque(['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], maxlen = 6)
        try:
            previous_row = data[name(row)][-1]
            previous_date = date(previous_row)
        except IndexError:
            previous_date = None
        if  previous_date == date(row):
            # use the xtra stuff from last time
            row.extend(sixplus(previous_row))
            # discard the previous row because
            # there is a new row with the same date
            data[name(row)].pop()
        else:
            # add columns 3 and 4 from each previous row
            for deck in data[name(row)]:
                # adding new items to a full deque causes
                # items to drop off the other end
                default.appendleft(deck[4])
                default.appendleft(deck[3])
            row.extend(default)
        writer.writerow(row)
        data[name(row)].append(row)
```

After thinking about that solution a bit over a glass of port I realized it was just way too complicated - that tends to happen when I try to be fancy.  Not really sure about the protocol so I'll leave it up - it does have a possible advantage of maintaining the previous 3 rows for each name.

Here is a solution using slices and a regular dictionary.  It only *keeps* the previously processed row.  Much simpler.  I kept the itemgetters, again for readability.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

fields = ['Datatitle', 'Date', 'Name', 'Score', 'Parameter',
          'LTscore', 'LTParameter', 'LTscore+1', 'LTParameter+1',
          'LTscore+2', 'LTParameter+3']

name = itemgetter(2)
date = itemgetter(1)
cols_sixplus = itemgetter(slice(6,None))
cols34 = itemgetter(slice(3, 5))
cols6_9 = itemgetter(slice(6, 10))
data_alt = {}

with open('data.txt') as infile, open('processed_alt.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    # comment out the next line if the data file does not have a header row
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        try:
            previous_row = data_alt[name(row)]
        except KeyError:
            # first time this name encountered
            row.extend(['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'])
            data_alt[name(row)] = row
            writer.writerow(row)
            continue
        if  date(previous_row) == date(row):
            # use the xtra stuff from last time
            row.extend(cols_sixplus(previous_row))
        else:
            row.extend(cols34(previous_row))
            row.extend(cols6_9(previous_row))
        data_alt[name(row)] = row
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I have found, for similar types of processing, that accumulating the rows and writing them in chunks, instead of individually, can enhance performance quite a bit. Also, if possible, reading the entire data file at once helps.

Comment: The second solution is cleaner and probably the better of the two.

Comment: fair play for saying so, I have been busy on other projects, but am back to test the solutions offered to award the bounty. Many thanks SMNALLY

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach -- the exact implementation depends on your data, but this should give you a good starting point.

You run two passes through the input CSV data.

1. On the first pass through the input, scan in the rows and create
   a dictionary.  The name can be used as the key, e.g.  `{'Tom' :
   [(date1, values),(date2, values)], 'George' : [(date1, values),
   (date2,values)]}`.  It may turn out that it's easier to work with
   nested dictionaries, e.g. `{'Tom' : {date1: values, date2: values},
   'George' : {date1: values, date2: values}}`.  More on the data
   structure below.
2. On the second pass through the input, you concatenate the original
       input data and the historical data from the dictionary to create the output data.

The way you select the historical data depends on the regularity of the input data.  For example, if the dates are sorted in ascending order and you've implemented a dictionary of lists, it could be as simple as taking slices from the relevant list, e.g. `dataDict['Tom'][i-3:i]`.  But since you mention that there could be multiple records for the same date, you probably need to do additional work.  Some possibilities are:

- Given the dictionary of lists approach, maintain the values as a list so there are no duplicate date entries, e.g. `{'Tom' :(date1, [val1, val2, val3]),(date2, values)], 'George' : [(date1, values),(date2,values)]}`.
- Given the dictionary of dictionaries approach, lookup the specific date ranges that you require.  In this case you'd probably need to check for KeyError exceptions, unless every single date is available consecutively.  You could also maintain an additional, sorted index of available dates.

Comment: " For example, if the dates are sorted in ascending order " my data is sorted in the same format as the example. Latest date at the bottom, earliest date at the top (not sure if this corresponds to ascending or decending)

Comment: Ok, so one of the approaches described in this answer should work just fine.  "ascending" typically refers to smallest to largest, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  If you try to write the code and come across issues, feel free to post again with details.

Answer (score 0):

I kept picking away at this because I have a similar, small, project. 
I'll post a second answer with an improvement using coroutines.  The process is similar to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897110/2823755) but it is faster (though I don't know why).  There are three coroutines - reader, processor and writer.  The code below shows some abbreviated profiler stats.

```
"""uses coroutines.

2 gig file, 1M lines, 2K characters/line:
- read and send one line at a time
- process and send one line
- accumulate 720 lines before write
Wed Nov 13 08:04:34 2013    fooprof
    10947682 function calls (9946973 primitive calls) in 82.147 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   82.147   82.147 <string>:1(<module>)
        1   59.896   59.896   82.147   82.147 optimizations.py:45(reader)
  1000710    8.864    0.000   21.703    0.000 optimizations.py:57(processor)
  1000710    1.506    0.000    6.137    0.000 optimizations.py:94(writer)
  1002098    0.185    0.000    0.185    0.000 {len}
  1000708    0.209    0.000    0.209    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
      2/1    0.073    0.036    0.078    0.078 {method 'close' of 'generator' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1937129    0.295    0.000    0.295    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
  1002097    3.115    0.000    3.115    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
2001416/1000708    0.839    0.000   22.172    0.000 {method 'send' of 'generator' objects}
  1000708    4.305    0.000    4.305    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
  1000708    0.823    0.000    0.823    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
     1390    2.033    0.001    2.033    0.001 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
        1    0.004    0.004    0.004    0.004 {method 'writelines' of 'file' objects}
        2    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {open}

Running a few in a row helps:
Fri Nov 15 22:12:02 2013    fooprof
    10947671 function calls (9946963 primitive calls) in 69.237 seconds
Fri Nov 15 22:13:44 2013    fooprof
    10947671 function calls (9946963 primitive calls) in 64.330 seconds

using a dummy reader that sends the same line 1M times
Wed Nov 13 13:36:57 2013    fooprof
    10004374 function calls (9004373 primitive calls) in 23.013 seconds

using dummy reader AND writer --> processor time
Wed Nov 13 13:45:08 2013    fooprof
    10001730 function calls (9001729 primitive calls) in 10.523 seconds

using a dummy processor and writer --> mostly reader time
Wed Nov 13 22:45:24 2013    fooprof
        6005839 function calls (5005131 primitive calls) in 24.502 seconds

using a dummy reader and processor --> writer time
Wed Nov 13 22:52:12 2013    fooprof
    6004374 function calls (5004373 primitive calls) in 24.326 seconds

"""

import csv
from operator import itemgetter

# data,01/09/13,george,219,dataa,text
# data,01/09/13,george,219,dataa,text,x,y,x,y,x,y
# just keep the previous row

fields = ['Datatitle', 'Date', 'Name', 'Score', 'Parameter',
          'LTscore', 'LTParameter', 'LTscore+1', 'LTParameter+1',
          'LTscore+2', 'LTParameter+3']

def reader(processor, filename = 'data.txt'):
    processor.next()
    with open(filename) as f:
        #skip the header
        f.next()
        for line in f:
            processor.send(line)
    processor.close()
    return 'done'

def processor(writer):
    """Process line and send to writer.

    line --> str, a complete row of data
    sends str
    """
    date = itemgetter(1)
    name = itemgetter(2)
    cols_sixplus = itemgetter(slice(6,None))
    cols34 = itemgetter(slice(3, 5))
    cols6_9 = itemgetter(slice(6, 10))
    data = {}
    writer.next()
    try:
        while True:
            line = yield
            row = line.strip().split(',')
            try:
                previous_row = data[name(row)]
            except KeyError as e:
                # first time this name encountered
                row.extend(['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'])
                data[name(row)] = row
                writer.send(','.join(row) + '\n' )
                continue
            if  date(previous_row) == date(row):
                # use the xtra stuff from last time
                row.extend(cols_sixplus(previous_row))
            else:
                row.extend(cols34(previous_row))
                row.extend(cols6_9(previous_row))
            data[name(row)] = row
            writer.send(','.join(row) + '\n')
    except GeneratorExit:
        writer.close()

def writer(filename = 'processed.txt', accum = 1000):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write('Datatitle,Date,Name,Score,Parameter,LTscore,LTParameter,LTscore+1,LTParameter+1,LTscore+2,LTParameter+3\n')
        try:
            while True:
                # dataout = list()
                dataout = list()
                while len(dataout) < accum:
                    dataout.append((yield))
                f.write(''.join(dataout))
        except GeneratorExit:
            f.writelines(dataout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cProfile, pstats

    cProfile.run("reader(processor(writer(accum = 720)), filename = 'biggerdata.txt')", 'fooprof')
    p = pstats.Stats('fooprof')
    p.strip_dirs().sort_stats(-1).print_stats()
```

If you look at the profiler times using dummy functions (mocks ?), they don't add up to the time for all three *real* functions - I don't understand this, yet, either.

I tried using linecache in the reader but it was slower.  I tried mmap in the reader, reading 200M chunks, but it was slower - probably because I used re.finditer() to pick out the lines.  I will probably revisit an mmap reader for my own purposes.

Comment: I was trying to find solutions that didn't read the whole file at once because, unfortunately, I just don't have the juice to test a solution that does.